# Convert JSON (one field) to CSV (one row with delimiter)

Tags: python, json, csv

I have a code that takes JSON from URL and saves it to CSV file.
The second code takes only one rowfrom the CSV file and puts a "," delimiter.

```
--Takes the JSON from URL and converts to CSV

res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()
data_f = data.decode('utf-8')
data_j = json.loads(data_f)['results']s']

with open("../lookups/customer_id.csv", 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as f:
    wr = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames = data_j[0].keys()) 
    wr.writeheader() 
    wr.writerows(data_j)
```

The output that I get is:

name, id
aaa, 111
bbb, 222
ccc, 333
ddd, 444
...

The second script takes the file (customer_id.csv) and coverts it to this format:

111,222,333,444

```
import csv, re

with open("../lookups/customer_id.csv", newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader, None)
    c=""
    for row in reader:
        c = c+","+row[1]
get_customer = re.sub('^,', '', c)

file1 = open("../lookups/customer_no_list", 'w')
file1.write(get_customer)
file1.close()
```

I would like to combine it to one file. I don't need in customer_id.csv, only the customer_no_list file.
Since my Python skills are not that good, what is a better solution?

Thanks

Comment: it would be helpful if you provide the json structure

Comment: [{'name': 'Pinky and the Brain', 'id': '2123434'}, {'name': 'Micki Mouse', 'id': '1002449'}, {'name': 'Pink Floyd', 'id': '2008477'}, {'name': 'Ozzy', 'id': '1954023'}]